# php mail function

Tags: php, email

i have been asked the php mail() function, is it send from linux ?or is it depend where the source code reside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sent from your server; if it's Linux, Linux will send it, if it's Windows, Window's will send it. If you want to use a different server to send your mail look into SMTP

Comment: Windows doesn't have its own MTA, so mail() uses the PHP-preconfigured SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation on mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

On Linux, the local `sendmail` binary is used.

On Windows, where there is no such binary, you need to specify a (local or remote) SMTP server to send out E-Mail (See the "Windows" comments in the documentation.)

For anything more complex - like using SMTP with authentication, or a remote SMTP server, sending out many mails at once, handling attachments etc. there are powerful PHP libraries like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) that can totally circumvent the `mail()` command. It is often a good idea to use one of those from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following link for detailed documentation of `mail()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php